Compute the right normalization when using a custom metric in scikit-learn KDE
I am interested in computing the probability distribution of some unit-vectors on the surface of the unit-sphere.
Those unit vectors come from the diagonalization of an inertia tensor, so the direction is defined but the sens is degenerated (this will be important later).
For doing that I am using the kernel density function of scikit-learn (sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity).
I'll include an example of the vectors and the weights for reproducibility (but the last ones are not really relevant for the question):
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import LeaveOneOut
from sklearn.neighbors import KernelDensity


nn = np.array([[ 0.03402818,  0.39301999,  0.91890009],
       [ 0.59206726,  0.80298496,  0.06834847],
       [-0.92554092,  0.34986418, -0.144807  ],
       [ 0.60773445,  0.79307238, -0.04117088],
       [ 0.18615284,  0.51452414,  0.8370257 ],
       [ 0.40394095,  0.22357499,  0.88704336],
       [ 0.16339813,  0.48618174,  0.85844532],
       [ 0.86968201, -0.24154248,  0.43047697],
       [-0.50666593, -0.83360426, -0.21998538],
       [-0.80594915,  0.46939866, -0.36070884],
       [ 0.03807831,  0.40621088,  0.91298563],
       [ 0.2755237 ,  0.22552711,  0.93446467],
       [ 0.02600335,  0.38454888,  0.92273831],
       [-0.96124128,  0.18894847, -0.20078269],
       [ 0.60268438,  0.79609915,  0.05475108],
       [-0.94328141,  0.30247806, -0.13684734],
       [ 0.43765748,  0.22873265,  0.86956156],
       [ 0.17128545,  0.50535992,  0.84573793],
       [ 0.39959667,  0.22321366,  0.88909964],
       [ 0.88907925, -0.21332485,  0.40500691],
       [-0.14413127,  0.18262637,  0.97256043],
       [ 0.27327328,  0.0623681 ,  0.95991246],
       [-0.13116824,  0.18737418,  0.97349156],
       [ 0.94248182, -0.22452222,  0.24762429],
       [-0.43556423,  0.19004559,  0.87986731],
       [ 0.94787827, -0.25737596,  0.1878414 ],
       [-0.46914909, -0.00164206, -0.88311745],
       [-0.05133885,  0.18431249,  0.98152597],
       [ 0.43146423,  0.015442  ,  0.90199787],
       [-0.88801615,  0.2035849 , -0.41228692],
       [ 0.29721996,  0.0539346 ,  0.95328451],
       [-0.14843932,  0.18290349,  0.97186011],
       [ 0.26234948,  0.06603363,  0.96271092],
       [ 0.94420917, -0.22516556,  0.2403529 ],
       [-0.45932668, -0.00433692, -0.88825683]])

weights = np.array([2.75792219, 2.80864853, 1.59750041, 4.20455058, 3.24719617,
       1.70647554, 3.74628944, 5.88323566, 2.60350748, 3.29570828,
       3.60952358, 1.21608154, 3.13088853, 1.48962109, 3.21465176,
       1.77468426, 1.50534637, 4.14162718, 1.54502792, 3.18413058,
       3.64251358, 3.65384557, 8.13181441, 3.02696656, 4.58928026,
       5.16233972, 3.38317826, 4.24850591, 4.63408708, 3.04477234,
       4.77449734, 3.59965002, 4.01439879, 3.25976281, 3.66809761])

And some auxiliary functions:
def _vec_to_coord(vec):
    """
    Form a set of unit vectors, 
    to longitude and latitude
    """ 
    longitude = np.arctan2(
            vec[:, 1],
            vec[:, 0],
    )
    latitude = np.arcsin(vec[:, 2])

    return longitude, latitude


def _gen_uGrid():
    """
    Generate a longitude-latitude grid, and the corresponding unit vectors.   
    """
    lon, lat = np.mgrid[-np.pi : np.pi : 100j, -np.pi / 2 : np.pi / 2 : 100j]
    nn = np.array(
        [
            (np.cos(lon) * np.cos(lat)).ravel(),
            (np.sin(lon) * np.cos(lat)).ravel(),
            np.sin(lat).ravel(),
        ]
    ).T
    return lon, lat, nn

I have taken two approaches, each one with its own caveats:

Project my vectors onto the unit-sphere and use the haversine metric.
In order to take into account the degeneration, what I did was to duplicate the dataset to the other half of the sphere.

Use a custom metric (which is 1 less the absolute value of the dot product):


def custom_metric(x, y):
    """
    Compute the distance between two unit vectors  
    """
    dist = 0
    for ii in range(len(x)):
        dist += x[ii] * y[ii]
    return 1 - abs(dist)

This has the advantage that I do not need to duplicate the dataset in order to account for vectors that may be in the other half of the sphere.
For the first case (i.e. the kernel with the haversine metric):
longitude, latitude = _vec_to_coord(nn)

# wrap ol the vectors in one half of the sphere and duplicate them 
msk = ~((longitude > -(np.pi / 2)) & (longitude < (np.pi / 2)))
longitude[msk] = longitude[msk] - np.sign(longitude[msk]) * np.pi
latitude[msk] = -latitude[msk]

# duplicate the sample to properly take into account the periodicity

duplicated_longitude = longitude - np.sign(longitude) * np.pi
duplicated_latitude = -latitude

latitude = np.concatenate([latitude, duplicated_latitude])
longitude = np.concatenate([longitude, duplicated_longitude])
sample_weights = np.concatenate([weights, weights])

# the haversine metric needs the latitude first
projected_coords = np.stack([latitude, longitude]).T 

# estiamte the best band with via LeaveOneOut cross-validation
nbins = 50
bandwidths = 10 ** np.linspace(-2, 1, nbins)
grid = GridSearchCV(
    KernelDensity(kernel="gaussian", metric="haversine"),
    {"bandwidth": bandwidths},
    cv=LeaveOneOut(),
    n_jobs=6,
    verbose=0,
)
grid.fit(projected_coords, sample_weight=sample_weights) 


# Now the ploting 
projection = "mollweide"
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection=projection))

X, Y = np.mgrid[-np.pi : np.pi : 100j, -np.pi / 2 : np.pi / 2 : 100j]
xy = np.vstack([Y.ravel(), X.ravel()]).T # the latitud first
Z = np.exp(grid.best_estimator_.score_samples(xy)).reshape(X.shape)

img = ax.pcolormesh(X, Y, Z)

fig.colorbar(img, orientation="horizontal")
ax.plot(longitude, latitude, ".", color="r")
ax.plot(duplicated_longitude, duplicated_latitude, ".", color="b")

ax.grid()
ax.set_title("haversine")

And for the second case (i.e. The custom metric):
sample_weights = weights

# estiamte the best band with via LeaveOneOut cross-validation
bandwidths = 10 ** np.linspace(-3, 0, nbins)
grid = GridSearchCV(
    KernelDensity(
        kernel="gaussian",
        metric="pyfunc",
        metric_params={"func": custom_distance},
    ),
    {"bandwidth": bandwidths},
    cv=LeaveOneOut(),
    n_jobs=6,
    verbose=0,
)
grid.fit(nn, sample_weight=weights)

X, Y, samples = _gen_uGrid()
Z = np.exp(grid.best_estimator_.score_samples(samples)).reshape(X.shape)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={"projection": "mollweide"})
img = ax.pcolormesh(X, Y, Z)
fig.colorbar(img, orientation="horizontal")
ax.plot(*_vec_to_coord(nn), "r.")
ax.grid()
ax.set_title("Custom Metric")


As you can see in the images, the custom metric and the haversine one produces very similar results in shape, but the absolute values are extremely different.
What may be the reason for this scaling of the densities?


